# Strange behaviour of Android HttpURLConnection.getInputStream in HTTP POST

Tags: java, android, spring, rest, httpurlconnection

The following code makes an HTTP POST to a REST API in Spring:

```
    ...
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream input = null;
    BufferedWriter output = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        //Send data
        output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream()));
        output.write(data);
        output.flush();
        //Read response
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode >= 400) {
            input = connection.getErrorStream();
        } else {
            input = connection.getInputStream();
        }
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        result = "Status " + responseCode + ".\n" + sb.toString();
        ...
```

Where url contains the REST API endpoint and data is a JSON converted to string with the user attributes needed in the POST.

The problem is that although the POST works as expected, I cannot get the response body returned by the API after I get a HTTP Status 201 (but it works in case of error, e.g. HTTP Status 409). Strangely the `readline()` function returns always null at the very first read. The API works perfectly calling it from `Postman`, even running that code from a Java project within `Eclipse`.

My `compileSdkversion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to 25.

I compared my code with a lot of `HttpURLConnection` samples around the net, applying changes here and there, but no success...

Any idea?

Comment: yet another sample u may review:  https://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing the HTTP headers sent from both `Postman` and the `Android` APP, I noticed that by adding the header `Accept: */*` to the POST request (as `Postman` does) it worked as expected. According to the [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2): *A request without any Accept header field implies that the user agent will accept any media type in response.*, so it should have worked without the Accept header (as the GET to the same API does).

For me it seems either a bug, a misconfiguration or a "normal" behaviour from the `Spring` API side, it has nothing to do with the Android `HttpURLConnection` module.